# close a thread resource properly in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a tomcat application, upon starting will run the following code(A scheduler which will run a task every 5 minutes).

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    HttpsTool.setupUncheckedHttps();
    LOGGER.info("DeploymentInfoScheduler Initialized successfully....");
    System.out.println("DeploymentInfoScheduler Initialized successfully....");
    this.retrieveServiceDeploymentsInfo();
}

private void retrieveServiceDeploymentsInfo() {
    final Runnable deploymentsDataHandler = new DeploymentsDataHandler();
    final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = deploymentsInfoRetrieverScheduler
            .scheduleAtFixedRate(deploymentsDataHandler, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);


}
```

Then inside the scheduler, the `DeploymentsDataHandler` looks like as follows:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        LOGGER.info("Now begin a new round of refreshing deployment data...");
        this.doWorkFlow();
    }catch(Exception e){
        LOGGER.info("something goes wrong...");
        LOGGER.error("Encountered an exception in this round of refreshing deployment data",e);
        try {
            EmailHandler.sendEmail(e.getMessage(), "dummymailaddress");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.error("cannot deliver this email about the exception");
        }
        return;
    }

}

private void doWorkFlow() {
    // step 1
    InitializationPageService initializationPageService = new InitializationPageService();
    List<ServiceRow> serviceList = initializationPageService
            .pageInitialization();
    System.out.println("Data Retrieved ....");
    LOGGER.info("service deployment time data are retrieved successfully");
    // step 2
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    for (ServiceRow serviceRow : serviceList) {
        Runnable worker = new DeploymentReasonHandler(serviceRow);
        executor.execute(worker);

        // executor.submit(worker);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        LOGGER.info("wait for up to 4 minutes to let all tasks getting deployments reason to be finished...");
        System.out.println("wait for up to 4 minutes to let all tasks getting deployments reason to be finished...");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        executor.awaitTermination(4, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOGGER.info(String.format(
                "All tasks getting deployments reason finished in %s ms",
                (end - start)));
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "All tasks getting deployments reason finished in %s ms",
                (end - start)));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Thread is interrupted while executing task to get a deployment reason..");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    // while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    // //System.out.println("still running...");
    // }
    LOGGER.info("*********** All Data Updated !***********");

}
```

Basically every 5 minutes, it will create a new *ThreadPool* with 20 threads and run some task and then shutdown the *ThreadPool* executor.

But after it runs about 1 or 2 days, some weird issue occurs and when I check the logs, I found something like:

> ```
> catalina.out.log.2016-09-27-18:Exception in thread "Thread-41085" 
> catalina.out.log.2016-09-27-18:Exception in thread "Thread-41256" 
> catalina.out.log.2016-09-27-18:Exception in thread "Thread-41201" 
> catalina.out.log.2016-09-27-18:Exception in thread "Thread-41605" 
> catalina.out.log.2016-09-27-18:Exception in thread "Thread-41933"
> ```

Does this mean it is creating 40000+ thread now, which means the threads created before are not closed properly? How could I improve the code?

Comment: try using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html

Comment: Why not use `executor.invokeAll(...)` instead of creating and destroying the thread pool every five minutes?